# Empty ${shlibs:Depends} while packaging a Mapnik plugin with cmake-based build system for Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: cmake, debian, packaging, mapnik

I am creating a Mapnik plugin (https://github.com/rbuch703/coords-mapnik-plugin), and am currently working on packaging it for Debian/Ubuntu. The binary package consists of only a single shared library that is built from C++ code. But being a Mapnik plugin, this library follows conventions quite different from the usual POSIX library conventions:

- the file name has to be `<name>.input` instead of `lib<name>.so`
- the file is installed in the Mapnik plugin directory (usually `/usr/lib/mapnik/input`)
- the file is not supposed to be found by `ldconfig`, but rather Mapnik tries to find the plugin by itself at runtime

Now the plugin's build system is `cmake`, which makes most parts of Debian packaging straight-forward: the `debian/rules` file contains only the basic lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
    dh $@
```

However, I am running into problems with the substitution variable {shlibs:Depends}: it is simply not set (in particular, there is no corresponding line in the `debian/<package name>.substvars` file), and Lintian rightly complains about that fact (Lintian's actual complaint is `missing-dependency-on-libc`. But when I manually add a libc dependency, Lintian explains `package-depends-on-hardcoded-libc`, which means "The given package declares a dependency on libc directly instead of using ${shlibs:Depends} in its debian/control stanza."). I would like to satisfy Lintian in than respect, but are unable to do so.

Now I found that I could add the line

```
dpkg-shlibdeps debian/<packagename>/usr/lib/mapnik/input/coords.input
```

to my `rules` file. That will create the correct `${shlibs:Depends}` line, but it will create it in the wrong file (`debian/substvars` instead of `debian/<package name>.substvars`), where the build system simply ignores it and Lintian keeps complaining about missing dependencies.

I am guessing that the root of my problem is that my Mapnik plugin does not conform to the POSIX library naming conventions (and as a Mapnik plugin cannot do so), and thus the packaging system does not handle it correctly. But I am at a loss as to how to fix this problem.

Additional notes:

- the packages are built using `debuild`. Apart from the Lintian error messages, the build process work fine and correctly creates the `.deb` package.
- my practical goal is for the package to build cleanly on Launchpad, so that I can add it to my Ubuntu PPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can provide an output file for `dpkg-shlibdeps` with the `-T` flag.
something like:

```
override_dh_shlibdeps:
        dh_shlibdeps
        dpkg-shlibdeps \
           -Tdebian/<packagename>.substvars \
           debian/<packagename>/usr/lib/mapnik/input/coords.input
```

if there are multiple **.input* files, you could also do something like:

```
override_dh_shlibdeps:
        dh_shlibdeps
        find debian/<packagename>/ -name "*.input" -exec \
            dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/<packagename>.substvars {} +
```

Comment: Great, works exactly as intended, and gets rid of the Lintian warning.

Comment: There's a small typo in your first code block (you wrote "dh_slibdeps" instead of "dh_s**h**libdeps".